# Return Col3 when searched by either Col1 or Col2

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

Have a question I can't solve.
Say we have three columns, in this case ID, Key and Name.

```
ID    Key    Name
--    ---    ----
1      9     John
2      6     Sally
```

I am trying to, in excel 2010 and with formula (VB would need ITSec approval)9, to allow a user to look up the name (John) with either ID or Key.  ID and Key are unique values and I won't know which the user will have/enter to search by.

I tried radio buttons and choose command with various iterations of index/match, vlookup/match - but no luck.

Can some one write a formula which will return Col3 (John) if a user enters ID(1) or Key(9) in a single search cell?

Comment: I would think it would have to be a two-part process, using Data Validation in one column and a formula in the next. The Data Validation offers two choices: "Search by ID" and "Search by Key". Then have a formula with an IF statement and a VLOOKUP. If the keys and IDs had very distinct patterns, not the case in your example, then I suppose you could do it all in one formula, where the IF determines which type of pattern they've entered, but that seems pretty error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the search value is entered in E1 and your data-set starts at A1:

> =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($E$1,$A$2:$C$3,3,0)),IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP($E$1,$B$2:$C$3,2,0)),"not
>   found",VLOOKUP($E$1,$B$2:$C$3,2,0)),VLOOKUP($E$1,$A$2:$C$3,3,0))